# Method for moving an element in an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm trying to create a simple method to move the first element in an array to the back of the array.

Here's my code

```
public class Ex5_ShiftLeft {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[] {6, 2, 5, 3};
    swap (a);

    }

    public static void swap(int[] array){
        array[0] = array[array.length];
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

Eclipse doesn't seem to detect an error with my code, but when I run it, I get the error text

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   4     at
>   apollo.exercises.ch04_loops.Ex5_ShiftLeft.swap(Ex5_ShiftLeft.java:19)
>     at
>   apollo.exercises.ch04_loops.Ex5_ShiftLeft.main(Ex5_ShiftLeft.java:1)"

Any tips?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays represent a segment of memory which your program has reserved to store a series of numbers or whatever else your array has. Because of this, arrays cannot be resized; you can't go past the end of the segment of memory you've reserved because another program might be using that memory. Your solution does not work because it tries to take the first element and put it after the end of the array, which is out of bounds. Instead, you have to remember the first element, then move each element except for the first one space to the left to create room at the end of the array, and then you can put the first element at the end of the array.

Answer (score 2):

I take it as you're a beginner so i'll say just keep at it and you'll sure improve. I improved your code below for you:

```
public class Ex5_ShiftLeft {    
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[] a =  {6, 2, 5, 3};
     swap (a);
}

public static void swap(int[] array){
    int temp = array[0]
    array[0] = array[array.length-1];
    array[array.length-1]

    for(int x : array){
       System.out.println(x+" ");
    }
  }
}
```

CHANGES:
You can declare an array just with this: int[] myArray = {6,2,5,3};

There was a problem with your swap function. You have to create temporary variable so you can swap the first element of the array with the last.Also, the last element of the array is array[array.length-1]

Second, I used an *Enhanced For-loop* to print out the array. Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, the last part of the swap function should be     array[array.length-1] = temp;

Comment: Thanks man! May I ask why do we have to create a temporary variable? Isn't array[0] a variable on its own?

Comment: If you take the first element and say this is the last element, where will you get the last element to say it's now the first element. You have to stored it in a temporary place, retrieve it and says it's now the first element

Answer (score 0):

The size of an array is basically static.
For this purposes, you can use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) which is dynamic.

Answer (score -1):

The error is because of line :

array[0] = array[array.length];

If you want to access the last element of the array and populate it to array[0] then use below

array[0] = array[array.length-1];

Comment: Correct, but doesn't solve the problem as he described in writing.

Answer (score -1):

Use `array[0] = array[array.length - 1];` to access the last item in the `Array`.

Comment: Correct, but doesn't solve the problem as he described in writing.